# syscall getpid, print the return?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I try to print the result of getpid syscall to stdout.

Here is my asm code :

```
;getpid.asm
[SECTION .txt]
global _start
_start:

    xor eax, eax    ; clean eax
    mov al, 20  ; syscall getpid
    int 0x80    ; execute

    push eax    ; put the return of getpid on the stack
    xor eax, eax    ; clean
    xor ebx,ebx ; clean
    xor ecx, ecx    ; clean
    xor edx, edx    ; clean
    mov al, 4   ; syscall for write
    mov bl, 1   ; stdout 1 in ebx
    pop ecx     ; put the value returned by getpid in ecx
    mov dl, 5   ; len of return value
    int 0x80    ; execute

    xor eax, eax    ; clean eax
    xor ebx, ebx    ; for exit (0)
    mov al, 1   ; syscall for exit
    int 0x80    ; execute
```

I compile with :

```
nasm -f elf getpid.asm; ld -o getpid getpid.o
```

Then I use strace to check :

```
~# strace ./getpid
getpid()               = 17890
write(1, 0X45e2, 5)    = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
_exit(O)                = ?

17890d = 45e2h
```

In fact, I give a value instead of a pointer to that value. I don't know how to do in this case : put the result of the getpid syscall in a variable ? then affect the address of this variable to ecx ?

Comment: Yes, put the pid in memory (can be the stack) and pass that address. Note that it will be in binary format, if you want human readable you will of course have to convert it to text first.

Comment: Thanks Jester ! Can you give me the code ? I started to learn ASM programming this afternoon, I don't know how to pass the address of the stack ? convert in text ?

Comment: You can find many examples of converting to text, it does take some effort in assembly, unfortunately. If you are happy with the binary result, just do something like: `mov ecx, esp` instead of the `pop ecx` and write 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to find (or understand) a good code for convert hex to string. However, I found a solution by using a C function printf

```
;getpid.asm
extern  printf

SECTION .data
  msg: db "PID= %d",10,0    ; 10 for \n, 0 and of the string, require for printf

SECTION .text
global main
main:

  push ebp                  ; save ebp
  mov ebp, esp              ; put the old top of the stack to the bottom
  sub esp, 100              ; increase the stack of 100 byte

  xor eax, eax              ; set eax to 0
  mov al, 20                ; syscall getpid
  int 0x80                  ; execute

  push eax                  ; put the return of the getpid on the stack
  push dword msg            ; put the string on the stack
  call printf
  add esp, 8                ; decrease esp of 8, 2 push

  leave                     ; destroy the stack

  xor eax, eax              ;
  xor ebx, ebx              ; for exit (0)
  mov al, 1                 ; syscall for exit
  int 0x80                  ; execute
```

Compile with :

```
nasm -f elf getpid.asm
gcc -o getpid getpid.o
```